# How do you run async tests in FsCheck?

Tags: asynchronous, f#, fscheck

How can I get repeatable async tests with FsCheck?  Here is a sample code that I run in FSI:

```
let prop_simple() = gen {
    let! s = Arb.generate<string>
    printfn "simple: s = %A" s
    return 0 < 1
}
let prop_async() =
    async {
        let s = Arb.generate<string> |> Gen.sample 10 1 |> List.head
        // let! x = save_to_db s // for example
        printfn "async: s = %A" s
        return 0 < 1
    } 
    |> Async.RunSynchronously

let check_props() = 
    //FC2.FsCheckModifiers.Register()
    let config = 
        { FsCheck.Config.Default with 
            MaxTest = 5
            Replay = Random.StdGen(952012316,296546221) |> Some
        }
    Check.One(config, prop_simple)
    Check.One(config, prop_async)
```

The output looks something like this:

```
simple: s = "VDm2JQs5z"
simple: s = "NVgDf2mQs8zaWELndK"
simple: s = "TWz3Yjl2tHFERyrMTvl0HOqgx"
simple: s = "KRWC92vBdZAHj6qcf"
simple: s = "CTJbQGXzpLBNn0RY6MCvlfUtbQhCUKm9tbXFhLSu0RcYmi"
Ok, passed 5 tests.
async: s = "aOE"
async: s = "y8"
async: s = "y8"
async: s = "q"
async: s = "q"
Ok, passed 5 tests.
```

Another run can look like this:

```
simple: s = "VDm2JQs5z"
simple: s = "NVgDf2mQs8zaWELndK"
simple: s = "TWz3Yjl2tHFERyrMTvl0HOqgx"
simple: s = "KRWC92vBdZAHj6qcf"
simple: s = "CTJbQGXzpLBNn0RY6MCvlfUtbQhCUKm9tbXFhLSu0RcYmi"
Ok, passed 5 tests.
async: s = "g"
async: s = "g"
async: s = "g"
async: s = ""
async: s = ""
Ok, passed 5 tests.
```

So `prop_simple()` works fine & is repeatable (given `StdGen(952012316,296546221)`).

But `prop_async()` is not repeatable & seems to generate the same strings over and over.

Also, is there a better way to write `prop_async()`?

Comment: I suspect your asyncs are kicking off close enough to simultaneously that you're getting the same timestamp-based random seed for several of them, and that's causing the repeated samples you're seeing. I'd recommend trying out https://github.com/haf/expecto/ which has a system for running FsCheck properties asynchronously. I've never used it so I can't give you more help than that, which is why this is a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: expecto looks really useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FsCheck's behavior doesn't really have anything to do with the `async` here, but rather with the fact that inside the `async` you're using `Gen.sample`. `Gen.sample` picks a new time-based seed for every invocation - so the behavior of it insides an FsCheck property is not reproducible. In other words you shouldn't ever use it inside a property, it's there just for exploratory purposes when you're writing a new generator. Since the seed is time-based, and your property is very small, multiple invocations will use the same seed and so you see the same values. As an example, here is a property without any `async` that has the same behavior:

```ml
let prop_simple2() =         
    let s = Arb.generate<string> |> Gen.sample 10 1 |> List.head
    // let! x = save_to_db s // for example
    printfn "simple2: s = %A" s
    0 < 1
```

prints e.g.

```
simple2: s = "nrP?.PFh^y"
simple2: s = "nrP?.PFh^y"
simple2: s = "nrP?.PFh^y"
simple2: s = "nrP?.PFh^y"
simple2: s = "nrP?.PFh^y"
Ok, passed 5 tests.
```

Now as for how to write an `async` property, I'd keep the asynchrony inside the property and then resolve it using `Async.RunSynchronously` to a normal value.As a variant on your example:

```ml
let prop_async2 =
    gen {
        let! s = Arb.generate<string>
        // let! x = save_to_db s // for example
        let r = 
            async {
                printfn "async2: s = %A" s
            }
            |> Async.RunSynchronously
        return 0 < 1
    }
```

Which has a deterministic output. (Note also if you're already creating a `Gen<'T>` instance you don't need to  make the property a function. You can, but that just means that FsCheck will generate 100 values for the `unit` type (these values are of course all `()` which is effectively `null`, so it doesn't hurt but is a small performance improvement.)

You can also do it the other way round:

```ml
let prop_async3 =
    async {
        let r = gen {
            let! s = Arb.generate<string>
            printfn "async3: s = %A" s
            return 0 < 1
        }
        return r
    }
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

A few gotchas to be aware of.

- Sequential asynchronous code should generally pose little problems, but read on.
- Asynchronous and *concurrent* code may run into issues like munn said in the comments, i.e. multiple threads/tasks using the same value. Also reproducibility will be affected. You can maybe carefully write your property code so you don't run into this (e.g. by having a prelude in your properties where all necessary values are first generated in a sequential fashion, then kick off the asynchronous functions), but it needs some work and thought.
- If you override `Arbitrary` instances using `Arb.register` they will be overridden in a *thread* local way; i.e. they won't be propagated to a sequence of async `Task`s. My advice is to just don't do that. Registered `Arbitrary` instances are essentially mutable static state and that generally doesn't play all that nice with concurrency.

Taken together I think `async` properties are definitely possible but it's definitely somehwat of an uphill battle in v2. FsCheck 3 (currently in alpha) supports async and multithreaded execution directly.

Comment: This also answers a lot of other questions I had. Thanks so much. Now I can make some really impressive tests!!